# Detected multiple Kotlin daemon sessions at build/kotlin/sessions

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, gradle

When building apk with `./gradlew assembleRelease` under Android for React Native 0.70.1/gradle 7.3.3/7.4.2/7.5.1/Android Studio 2021.3.1/macOS Monterey, it failed with error. The app runs fine (`npx react-native run-android`) on Android simulator:

```
> Task :rn-alioss:verifyReleaseResources FAILED
w: Detected multiple Kotlin daemon sessions at build/kotlin/sessions

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':rn-alioss:verifyReleaseResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.tasks.VerifyLibraryResourcesTask$Action
   > Android resource linking failed
     ERROR:/Users/macair/Documents/code/js/xyz_app6/node_modules/rn-alioss/android/build/intermediates/merged_res/release/values/values.xml:2723: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/lStar not found.
```

Here is the portion in values.xml mentioned in the error:

```
<declare-styleable name="ColorStateListItem">
    
    <attr name="android:color"/>
    
    <attr format="float" name="alpha"/>
    <attr name="android:alpha"/>
    
    <attr format="float" name="lStar"/>
    <attr name="android:lStar"/>. //<<==line# 2723 mentioned in error above
  </declare-styleable>
```

It is a common error related to gradle but solutions posted were not working in my case. What I did was to downgrade gradle from 7.5.1 to 7.4.2 with:

```
./gradlew wrapper --gradle-version 7.4.2 --distribution-type=all
```

Then downgrade to `7.3.3` and the error remains the same. Deleting `android/.gradle` and `./gradlew clean` didn't help. Adding `org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4g -XX:MaxPermSize=2048m ,,,,` to /android/gradle.properties causing error of `MaxPerSize unrecognized`.

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Comment: A post has to first of all explain the true question or tech difficulty, what has happened, what has tried. Adding a few words thanking the community does not negate  the tech effort as I understand.

Comment: [This post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288160/no-thanks-damn-it) is a fairly canonical answer to your question.

Comment: What does `gradle --stop` do? @user938363

Comment: Not exactly sure about what `grade --stop` does. It may jump start gradle again. Just got it from a online post. it seems a common issue but solution online seem all over the places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature `"android:lStar"` requires compileSdk 31.

So one possible solution is upgrade the compileSdkVersion to 31.

If you do not want this, maybe your project or some dependencies has `androidx.core:core-ktx:+`, which dosno‘t limit the version or has `1.7` and above. So change it in your build.gradle :

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'androidx.core:core:1.6.0'
        force 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0'
    }
}
```

Hope this can help you!

Comment: Hi there, the compileSdkVersion was 31. Also tried 33. The error is the same. I noticed this android.core:core:1.6.0 mentioned in some solution post. However I was not not able to find it in the module. BTW `./gradlew bundleRelease` works fine when generating abb file.

Comment: Tried to put the `configurations.all {...}` bloc in build.gradle under android and android/app/src, one at a time. Unfortunately the error is the same. The error seems very sticky. Before that it was fine on RN 0.68.2

Comment: Put `configurations.all {....} bloc to module rn-alioss's build.gradle and `./gradlew assembleRelease` runs successfully. Maaaany thanks.

Comment: where I need to add please anyone help me I am facing this error: e: /Users/mac/Desktop/Ravindra/RoboBackup_20_oct/Awesome/node_modules/react-native-pager-view/android/src/main/java/com/reactnativepagerview/PagerViewViewManager.kt: (57, 15): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.6.0, expected version is 1.1.15.